# Remove session ASP.NET c# when the user close the tab

Tags: asp.net, session

I need to close the session when the user close the tab or the browser because  important information and transactions are manage. could someone help me, please or tell me if is not a standard idea for a web page. Thanks

Comment: You can detect when the user leaves the page (either by requesting another page in the same tab or closing the tab) by using the `window.onbeforeunload` (should use `window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(){ /* AJAX call here*/ }`), but I do not think there is any warranty that the AJAX call will be made in all browsers.

Comment: But this event is not only for close tab right?

Comment: No. There is no event for tabs being closed as there is no event for browser being closed (for that matter, use sessions). Don't forget that the user is also responsible for his/her security. If you really, really want to be strict, use unique tokens between all requests (for example, the users logs in, then all links in the page contain the key `X`. When the user clicks on a link, the key is sent within the url and a new key, let's say `Y`, is generated and applied to all links, ...). It's annoying: back button is not allowed, if the user closed the tab and reopens it, he has to log in again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this as HTTP is a stateless protocol. You have no way of knowing if they've finished or are just waiting, with an open browser doing nothing.

Your main option is Session timeout - you could reduce the timeout in order to close inactive sessions faster, but this may cause legitimate users to have their issues with the session timing out before they are done.

You could write some JavaScript to make a async call to drop the session based on inactivity. (Like how online banking would sign you out).